# Adding a row with a button in Kendo Grid

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm now trying to add an additional row to the top of the table with 3 side by side buttons. Do I need to add any HTML or is it somehow dynamically added via js? Sort of like the url below but it's just a button (possibly an image) and not a dropdown (these will be controls like edit, delete and add columns buttons):

http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/toolbar-template.html

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <link href="styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="styles/kendo.blueopal.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/kendo.web.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


</head>
<body>
<div id="grid"></div>

<script>
$(function(){

   var people = [{patientName: "John Doe", MRN: "464684778", account: "56765765224768", dateOfBirth: "01/06/2013", room: 403, bed: 22, admitDate: "01/15/2013" },

   {patientName: "John Doe", MRN: "464684778", account: "56765765224768", dateOfBirth: "01/06/2013", room: 403, bed: 22, admitDate: "01/15/2013" },

   {patientName: "Jane Doe", MRN: "464684778", account: "56765765224768", dateOfBirth: "01/06/2013", room: 403, bed: 22, admitDate: "01/15/2013" },

   {patientName: "Bert Jones", MRN: "464684778", account: "56765765224768", dateOfBirth: "01/06/2013", room: 403, bed: 22, admitDate: "01/15/2013" },

   ];


   $("#grid").kendoGrid({
     columns: [{field: "patientName", title: "Patient Name"},
               {field: "MRN", title: "MRN"},
               {field: "account", title: "Account#"},
               {field: "dateOfBirth", title: "Date of Birth"}, 
               {field: "room", title: "Room"},
               {field: "bed", title: "Bed"},
               {field: "admitDate", title: "Admit Date" }],
     dataSource: {
       data:people
     },

     height:300,
     scrollable:true,
     pageable: true,
     pageSize: 2,
     sortable: true                
  });

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `toolbar` section to your kendoGrid config, and supply a list of buttons that you want to add:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
     columns: [{field: "patientName", title: "Patient Name"},
               {field: "MRN", title: "MRN"},
               {field: "account", title: "Account#"},
               {field: "dateOfBirth", title: "Date of Birth"}, 
               {field: "room", title: "Room"},
               {field: "bed", title: "Bed"},
               {field: "admitDate", title: "Admit Date" }],

     toolbar: [
       {"name": "create"}, 
       {"name": "save"}, 
       {"name": "cancel"}
     ],

     dataSource: {
       data:people
     },

     height:300,
     scrollable:true,
     pageable: true,
     pageSize: 2,
     sortable: true                
  });
```

If you can't get things to look the way you want with the toolbar, you can supply your own HTML to this option:

```
toolbar: "<div>stuff here</div>"
```

There's more info in the docs, here: http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#toolbar-array

Comment: Derick, say I wanted to add three images (that would be clickable) to the right side of the top bar that would act on the data below - like update, delete, refresh - would that be done via templates? Not quite sure I understand templates (yet)